# Unable to scrape data using selenium find_element_by_class_name() in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to webscraping & not a developer nor have any html exp. and was trying to pull some details from my account after logging in into the website but getting errors in `find_element_by_class_name()`

this is the code I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.URL.COM") 

# logged into account manually & maneuvered to the page manually

driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-901oao css-cens5h r-1khnkhu r-13awgt0 r-1oke55r r-1enofrn r-1wzrnnt')
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14516/1270707966.py in <module>
----> 1 driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-901oao css-cens5h r-1khnkhu r-13awgt0 r-1oke55r r-1enofrn r-1wzrnnt')

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_class_name(self, name)
    562             element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')
    563         """
--> 564         return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
    565 
    566     def find_elements_by_class_name(self, name):
```

Also tried

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css-901oao css-cens5h r-1khnkhu r-13awgt0 r-1oke55r r-1enofrn r-1wzrnnt')
```

From `inspect` I was able to view this & tried to extract the one highlighted in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class name expect a single class name. where as you are passing multiple class name here

```
css-901oao css-cens5h r-1khnkhu r-13awgt0 r-1oke55r r-1enofrn r-1wzrnnt
```

It won't work.

Instead

remove the spaces and make a CSS selector out of it.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.css-cens5h.r-1khnkhu.r-13awgt0.r-1oke55r.r-1enofrn.r-1wzrnnt")
```

Also, Please remember `find_element_by_class_name` have been deprecated in newest selenium. You should use this instead

```
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name")
```

having said this, the locator that you've right now looks brittle in nature. Please use static attribute values.

You could try this **xpath**

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'css')]//div[@dir='auto' and contains(@style,'-webkit-line-clamp')]
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'css')]//div[@dir='auto' and contains(@style,'-webkit-line-clamp')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: When I try `driver.find_element_by(` I get an error `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by'`. So I tried `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.css-cens5h.r-1khnkhu.r-13awgt0.r-1oke55r.r-1enofrn.r-1wzrnnt")` but then I get error: `NameError: name 'By' is not defined`

Comment: My bad man ! there was a typo, I corrected it. Please try now.

Comment: yes, even I thought its probably a typo so I tried `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.css-cens5h.r-1khnkhu.r-13awgt0.r-1oke55r.r-1enofrn.r-1wzrnnt")` but then I get error: `NameError: name 'By' is not defined`. Do i need to define `By` somewhere ???

Comment: Please import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: Good evening to you too but I guess I will be spending my evening scratching my head on this as I have not got any data in this. On doing this `table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.css-cens5h.r-1khnkhu.r-13awgt0.r-1oke55r.r-1enofrn.r-1wzrnnt")` I get `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0c6828a508381ec0dad8aa58c1e6b32d", element="2f5826d9-7041-4146-b9ff-707b28cf8eb5")>` & if I try `results = []
for tag in table:
    results.append(tag.text)
print(results)` then I get `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

Comment: When we use `find_element` it returns a single web element, so in your case it would be `table`, now to extract text just use `table.text` or `table.get_attribute('innerText')`

Comment: In case of iteration like you are doing there `for tag in table:`, it should be `find_elements` not `find_element`

Comment: by using `find_elements` it worked for me. thanks alot for staying here & helping me out through this. Really really Appreciate that :)